# Powershell script to capture dump using DebugDiag?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that can capture dump using debug diag for an IIS appPOOL.
i can work on a .VB script however business demands powershell script in this case.

I am unable to find any related post on internet. 
As of now i dont even know, if we have a powershell module for debug diag.
Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native way to capture IIS App pool dumps. But you can convert this batch script to PS:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list wps /apppool.name:"Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool" /text:WP.NAME > "%temp%\tfspid.txt"

:: ProcDump.exe (faster, reflects/clones the process for the dump to minimize the time the process is suspended (Windows 7 and higher only))

for /F %%a in (%temp%\tfspid.txt) do "%~dp0\procdump.exe" -accepteula -64 -ma -r %%a f:\dumps

pause
```

Reference Link: [APP Pool Dump](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2012/07/02/how-to-take-a-memory-dump-of-an-asp-net-application-pool-quickly/)